# Tengo un problema al mostrar un ListView en un Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-listview

Tengo un problema al tratar de mostrar un `listview` en un `fragment`. El `listview` me aparece en blanco, pero cuando pongo un punto de ruptura todo va perfecto.
Este es el codigo de mi `fragment`:

```
public class ListRequestFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private View rootView;
    private ListView listView;
    private RequestAdapter adapterListView;
    private ArrayList<Solicitudes> _solicitudes;
    private int counter = 0;
    private RequestTask mAuthTask = null;
    private ProgressBar request_progress;
    private String _tipoServicio = null;
    private Button btnActualizar;

    public ListRequestFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_request, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        _tipoServicio = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("TipoServicio"): "";

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        attemptRequest();
        this.listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        adapterListView = new RequestAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_list_request, _solicitudes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    private void attemptRequest() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        if (_tipoServicio == null) {
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!cancel) {
            mAuthTask = new RequestTask(_tipoServicio);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String tipoServicio;

        RequestTask(String servicio) {
            tipoServicio = servicio;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            try {
                Service gestor = new Service();
                _solicitudes = gestor.GetSolicitudesByTipoServicio(tipoServicio);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            return _solicitudes != null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;

            if (!success) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se pudo cargar los datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Y este es mi adaptador:

```
public class RequestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Solicitudes> list = null;

    public RequestAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Solicitudes> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Solicitudes getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.profile_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblProfileName);
            holder.profile_address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblProfileAddress);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Solicitudes currentSolicitud = getItem(position);
        holder.profile_name.setText(currentSolicitud.getNombresCliente() + " "  + currentSolicitud.getApellidosCliente());
        holder.profile_address.setText(currentSolicitud.getCallePrincipal() + " y " + currentSolicitud.getCalleSecundaria());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView profile_name;
        private TextView profile_address;
    }
}
```

Comment: podes confirmar que el getView se esta llamando para todos los elementos? y por favor inclui el codigo el layout

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias.

Comment: por favor marca la respuesta como respondida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, seguramente sucede porque tienes un proceso asyncrono el cual llena los datos, y es así, tienes un AsyncTask, en este caso lo que se realiza es actualizar los datos del `adapter` y el `ListView` al llamarse el método `onPostExecute()`, donde se asegura la obtención de datos y terminación del proceso asincrono.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;

            if (!success) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se pudo cargar los datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
              //*** Actualiza datos.
            }


        }
```

Comment: Exactamente ese era el problema,.